# Google Chrome on OSX - disable password autofill

Tags: google-chrome, password, keychain

How can I disable password autofill/autosave in Google Chrome without deleting all my passwords from the Keychain? I tried just disabling autofill, but Chrome keeps filling out passwords and still conflicts with LastPass.

I want to keep the passwords in the Keychain to use them on my iPhone/iPad with iCloud Keychain, but in Chrome I only want to use LastPass. Using Lastpass and Chrome autofill together does not really work properly, since they seem to conflict. I have to try multiple times to fill out login data etc.

Any help is much appreciated. Or should I file a bugreport with Chrome?

Comment: file a bugreport anyway, Chrome needs some major overhaul.

Comment: Filed a bugreport: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347083&thanks=347083&ts=1393410783

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome, open the Preferences

scroll down and use Advanced

Find Passwords and Forms and un-check it.

[image]

To prevent Chrome using already stored passwords remove it in keyhain.

You have to do that for every Chrome password saved in keychain :(

[image]

Comment: As I said, this does not prevent chrome from filling out previously saved passwords (at least for me). Did you try it?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question? you want to keep the Chrome passwords in keychain but you do not want Chrome to use them?

Comment: Exactly, but Chrome seems to use it anyway even if Autofill is disabled.

Comment: see my update :)

Comment: Thanks, I will upvote your answer but this is not a solution for me - I have more than 1,000 passwords saved and will certainly not go through them one-by-one. I filed a bug report with Chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347083&thanks=347083&ts=1393410783

Comment: Thanks, while waiting are you interested in Apple script to do that for you (disable Google Chrome access to keychain)? We would have to find one first, or ask a new question here.

Comment: It would be great to have an Apple script to toggle Chrome access to the keychain passwords. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Open Safari. Click Preferences on the top left next to the Apple logo. A box appears. You can now see Autofill on top. Click Autofill. Now select or unselect as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. But this is how to deal with password autofill in Safari; tholu was asking about Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein to Buscar's solution. A way of getting chrome to forget already entered passwords and usernames is to clear browser history. Chrome -> Clear Browsing Data -> Make sure the passwords checkbox is selected and that "Obliterate the following items from:" is set sufficiently far back.

Answer (score 0):

This is working with my Google Chrome.

Just go into History in Chrome or Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and clear your history. Obliterate the following items from the beginning of time. Then uncheck the password check button and hit clear browsing data.

[image: Please Check this]